# How to distribute values linearly

Tags: javascript, distribution

I have a total of 10,000 that I want distributed among 99 points, not divided equally but on an increasing linear curve. So while the first point may be worth only [e.g.] 10, each following point would be worth more until the final one is worth [e.g.] 250 or so. But all points need total the 10,000. How could I do that?

// Edit: The first and last values of 10 and 250 are just examples, they could be anything really. The total though (10,000) needs to be variable, so I could change it to 20,000 later if needed.

Comment: The answer I get is x_i = 10 + 9010*i/4851 for i=0,1,2,...,98. But the last cell x_98 is about 192, not 250. If you need the first cell to be 10 and the last to be 250 with 99 points, that is not possible.

Comment: Is it increasing linear *or* in a curved manner?

Comment: I just added some clarification on the question (I didn't expect answers that didn't include the 10,000 in them!) But that total figure needs to be variable, but the first and last values are just examples and can be flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the 99 cells with values `[1,2,3,4,..,99]` and multiply each number by `S/4950` where `S` is the desired sum (e.g. S=10,000).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I need a solution where the 10,000 total is variable.

Comment: Thanks Matt! I wondered how you got the 4950 figure but then realized that's the sum of 1 to 99.

Comment: @qaiser [Here is the link to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

Starting at 3, and going up to 199, across 99 points, totaling 10,000. Is this a HW question?

```
var total = 0;
for (var i = 1; i < 100; i += 1) {
    total += i * 2 + 1;
}
alert(total);
```

Comment: "HW" as in hardware? I'm actually trying to distribute a game's rewards increasing gradually level-by-level in the game. But that 10,000 needs to be variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty vague but if the first point has value `X` and the gap between successive points is `Y` then the total of 99 such points is

```
 (99 * X) + (0.5 * 99 * 98 * Y)
```

You can use this formula to play around with a suitable value of `X` and `Y` such that your total of 10,000 is satisfied. For example you could fix `X` first then solve the total for `Y`  but this may not yield an integer result which may make it unsuitable. Unfortunately for certain totals there may not be integer solutions `X` and `Y` but your requirements seem rather arbitrary so I am sure you can use the above to arrive at a suitable value of `X`,`Y` and the total for your needs. It may serve you until you get a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I need a solution where the 10,000 total is variable.

Comment: @Essential I think you didn't understand the answer. I said you can use this as a guideline for ANY total - the expression above IS the total given start point with value X and spacing length Y between successive points.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar thing I wanted to do. Even though it is a bit late, perhaps this can help others.

Came up with the following:

```
var total = 10000;
var len_array = 99;
var points_array = [];
var next_no 
var sum_check =0;
for (var i = 0; i < (len_array); i += 1) {
    next_no = ((1-  i/len_array)/(0.5 * len_array + 0.5)) * total
    points_array.push(next_no);
    sum_check = sum_check + next_no;
}
```